# php call a js function that is defined on different js file

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to call

this js function that is stored on a file called default.js from a php file.

```
function myfunction(score) {
    console.log("got here");
    alert(score);
}
```

so this is the call for the js function on my php code but it does not work.

```
<!-- myfunction js file ↓ -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/default.js"></script>
<?php
    if ($grade=="100%"){
        // not able to call
        echo "myfunction($grade)";
    }
    else{
        echo "alert(\"haha\")";
    }
?>
```

Comment: For what I see on your code you're just echoing the function name into the HTML area without any context, try to put some <script></script> tags outside the <?php ?> ones so the code knows that the echo must be executed as javascript. I guess you just got the "myfunction(100%)" text outputed

Comment: In the above `$grade` is tested for with a percentage sign which makes it a *string* variable?! So you need to use quotes around that variable when calling `myfunction($grade)` - perhaps `myfunction('$grade')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this you will get the accurate result

```
<?php
    if ($grade == "100%") {
    ?>
        <script>
            myfunction('<?=$grade?>');
        </script>
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
    <script>
    alert('in');
    </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

you forgot about the `<script>` tags
change your `echo` like this:

```
echo "<script>myfunction('$grade')</script>";
```

you need to wrap `'` around the $grade because you're passing a string

---

or put `<script>` before the opening php tag and `</script>` after the end of php tag

Answer (score 0):

This is your Code.

Define $grade too in PHP or you get a
`<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined variable $grade in <b>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/default.js"></script>
<script>
<?php
    $grade = "10%";
    if ($grade=="100%"){
        echo "myfunction('$grade')";
   }
    else{
       echo 'alert("haha");';
 }
            
?>
</script>
```

Dont forget the `<script></script>` for javascript code inside html.